# Formatting left join in mysql select( Not showing all records in left table)

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

I have following sql

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT sample_register.usin,
          Date_format(sample_register.doc, '%d-%m-%Y') AS doc1,
          sample_register.location,
          sample_register.description,
          gamma_results.act,
          gamma_results.act_sd,
          gamma_results.mdl,
          gamma_results.bdl
   FROM   sample_register
          LEFT JOIN gamma_results
                 ON gamma_results.usin = sample_register.usin
   WHERE  Mid(sample_register.usin, 3, 1) = 'F'
          AND sample_register.doc BETWEEN'2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-26'
          AND sample_register.type <> 'WATER'
          AND gamma_results.istp = 'Cs137'
   ORDER  BY Mid(sample_register.usin, 3, 1),
             sample_register.doc,
             sample_register.usin) AS a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT sample_register.usin,
                    gamma_results.act,
                    gamma_results.act_sd,
                    gamma_results.mdl,
                    gamma_results.bdl
             FROM   sample_register
                    LEFT JOIN gamma_results
                           ON gamma_results.usin = sample_register.usin
             WHERE  Mid(sample_register.usin, 3, 1) = 'F'
                    AND sample_register.doc BETWEEN
                        '2014-09-01' AND '2014-09-26'
                    AND ( sample_register.type <> 'WATER' )
                    AND gamma_results.istp = 'k40'
             ORDER  BY Mid(sample_register.usin, 3, 1),
                       sample_register.doc,
                       sample_register.usin) AS b
         ON a.usin = b.usi
```

It gives me only 2 rows . There are 30 records meeting the where clause in sample_register and 4 records corresponding to 2 USIN in gamma_results. I want all the 30 records in sample_register joined with gamma_results, where data is available for only 2 USINs. Remaining 28 records in sample_register, the returned field values can be null. I found that if I am removing the condition gamma_results_istp then all the 30 records are shown. But I do not want this. Any suggestions please .

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but probably that you must transfert the condition gamma_results_istp from the Where operator to the ON operator; otherwise it is applied after the Left Join has been performed, not before:

```
... On (gamma_results.usin = sample_register.usin and gamma_results.istp='Cs137')
```

Repeat the same for your second gamma_results.istp condition.

Also, simplifying your example in order to show us only what's relevant wouldn't have hurt anyone.